# Ударение в фамилии Шетошин

Tags: орфоэпия, фамилии

Где ударение в фамилии Шетошин:

- на **о**,
- на **е**
- или на **и**?

Comment: Ударения в фамилиях определяется носителем (обычно - по семейной традиции), никакие иные "правила" не могут быть приняты во внимание как аргумент. Этот взгляд на проблему ударения и другие точки зрения вы найдёте здесь, пользуясь окном "Поиск по сайту".

Answer (score -1):

Будь фамилия славянской, она безоговорочно имела бы ударение на среднем слоге - Шет**о**шин.

Но Инет обнаруживает только какого-то французского Жоржа... так и судьба ему произноситься Шетош**и**н!

> Затем **французская компания** по производству женского белья
>   "Боле­ро" создала лифчик на магнитных застежках. Специалисты компании
>   все­гда считали систему крепления предыдущих бюстгальтеров, когда
>   при­ходилось сцеплять крючки лифчика перед собой, а затем
>   разворачивать его на 180 градусов, варварской. Причину этого объяснил
>   **консультант компании психолог Жорж Шетошин**, который провёл
>   специальное исследо­вание на тему застёжек женских бюстгальтеров.

Но даже если ненароком французской компании прислуживает русак 
Chetochine Georges ‐ Шет**о**шин Георгий Георгиевич, он однозначно становится  Жоржем Шетош**и**н (с Жоржем Шетош**и**н**о**м).

[источник](https://www.rulit.me/books/etyudy-o-mode-read-344879-39.html)

> По мнению французского эксперта в области современной розничной
>   торговли Жоржа Шетошин, журналисты совершают огромную ошибку,
>   квалифицируя сети Allkauf или Verkauf как гипермаркеты.

[источник](https://www.retail.ru/articles/18547/)

---

Кстати о птицах. Есть русская фамилия  [Шато́хин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%AF%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) ([Шето́хин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%9D%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9_%D0%98%D0%BE%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)).

> [Фамилия Шатохин](http://www.ufolog.ru/names/order/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%BD) образована от прозвища Шатоха, восходящего к
>   глаголу «шататься». Соответственно, его могли дать человеку праздному,
>   а также непоседливому или неуверенному в себе. Однако в некоторых
>   говорах Шатохой называли беглого бродягу.

А Гугл-переводчик упорно хочет видоизменить фамилию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну Четох**и**н он, что ты будешь делать! Слушать [здесь](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=fr&tl=ru&text=Georges%20Ch%C3%A9tochine).

На языке оригинала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И по-нашенски (якобы):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ещё информация; не знаю, тот ли Жорж (год рождения не совпал), но обратите внимание на отчество - Владимирович! Так что речь, скорее всего, об офранцузившейся русской фамилии:

**[CHETOCHINE (Georges)](https://www.whoswho.fr/decede/biographie-georges-chetochine_26842)**

> Président de société. Né le 12 avril 1937 à Paris 18e. Fils de Georgy
>   Wladimirovitch Chetochine, Officier, et de Mme, née Mercedes Gomez.
>   Mar. le 10 décembre 1977 à Mlle Françoise Biscard (3 enf.: Alexandra,
>   Vladimir, Guy Tran et 2 enf. d'un précédent mariage: Caroline, Orso).